# Конструктор сайтов

Tags: apache, nginx, php, mysql

Пришло время написать не сложный конструктор сайтов, только вот есть не большая проблема, я вообще не представляю как работают такие системы.

допустим:

```
site.ru - конструктор.
t.site.ru - созданный сайт
```

1. Как работает создание сайта, поддомена?
2. Как работает формирование сайта?
3. Как работает FTP для каждого сайта?

Comment: Что значит пришло время? Время приедет тогда когда вы будете понимать как оно работает. Вам нужно почитать литературу по содержанию a.k.a обслуживанию сервера и под накачать скилл серверных языков.

Comment: @Darix я до этого писал разные сайты, теперь предложили попробовать написать конструктор. С языками проблем как-бы нет.

Comment: >    Что значит пришло время?  

Валера, пришло твоё время))

Comment: @nikita_sergeevich настало, а не пришло.

Comment: Мне всегда казалось, что конструктор сайтов - это типа "взял хедер, футер, поле контента и 3 модуля, соединил и вот он - сайт". Вы пытаетесь сделать "автонастройщик сервера".

Comment: Как минимум нужно поднять свой сервер!

Comment: @Palmervan есть такое дело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструктор сайтов - это взял и перенаправил все запросы поддоменов на один DpcumentRoot, там где установлен мультисайтовый CMS (к примеру, wordpress). То есть все запросы типа test.site.ru, test2.site.ru итд ссылаются на одну папку, на один CMS и в зависимости от домена подгружает конфиг и далее дело за самой CMS. Можно легко переделать любой CMS мультисайтовым... достаточно сделать файл конфига динамическим и передавать движку

Comment: Это понятно. 

Создание ftp аккаунта, выделение необходимого дискового пространства для сайта. Это как делать?

Comment: Чтобы решить эти задачи, для начала попробуйте в ручную всю процедуру добавления и квотирования пользователей в руяную в шелле. Затем это повтороите скриптом.