# Создание нового FTP-аккаунта

Tags: ftp, shell, php

Как с помощью PHP-функции `system` и `shell` скрипта создать **FTP-аккаунт**?

У меня **VDS**, панель — **ISPManager Lite**, FTP-сервер — **vsftpd**.

Этот вопрос имеет отношение к [**этому вопросу**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/81688/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: А какой конкретно FTP-сервер установлен в Вашей системе? Например так средствами ОС (читать как shell в php) добавляется новый пользователь в Pure FTPd.
http://ru.opensuse.org/SDB:%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_FTP_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_Pure-ftpd

Comment: @ReinRaus, ответ в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю достаточно добавить пользователя в систему, там ftp-сервер сам подхватит...у меня на VDS так настроено все... сервер - Proftpd

Comment: Ок, хорошо. Как добавить нового пользователя с помощью PHP?

Comment: http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=adduser&category=8&russian=1

Answer (score 1):

Хотел подробно описать, но больно много писать придется. Тем более, что это все уже давно написано.
Устанавливаем vsftpd на Ubuntu

```
apt-get install vsftpd
```

Открываем папку /usr/share/doc/vsftpd/examples
Для виртуального хостинга желательно изучить 3 примера:
internet_site
virtual_hosts
virtual_users